# Package dcolumn displays different fonts

Tags: fonts, dcolumn

I stumbled across an interesting feature of dcolumn today.

I am using ITC Stone Serif fonts as they have been defined in our corporate design.  I prepared an LaTeX document via `lualatex`, using the Stone fonts.  That document also contained a tabular, using a `D` column from package `dcolumn`.  In the `D`-columns, LateX uses a different font than the loaded Stone font.

I was able, to replicate this problem, with package `bookman` (as Stone is copyrighted and hence not reproducible freely).

**UPDATE**  Ulrike Fischer suggested to use package `siunitx` and instead of a `D`-Column a `S`-column.  I updated my MWE to incorporate this suggestion.  As you can see, the `S`-column produces the exact same result (in respect to the fonts), as the `D`-column before.  (To be true, there is a slight difference: in the `S`-column the input had a comma as decimal separator, while the output presents a dot.)

Here is my **updated** MWE, I added package `siunitx` and a tabular consisting of column `S`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
12,34\\
\begin{tabular}{S}
  12,34
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{D{,}{,}{2}}
  12,34
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}%
```

And this is the **updated** result.

[image]

This is an excerpt from my original problem file, using the stone fonts:

[image]

Please compare the digit "2" in that case.

How can I achieve, that the default font (Stone in this case) is used?

Comment: As the documentation says on its first page "It should be
noted that dcolumn always uses math mode for the digits as well as the separator.". Use siunitx and its S-column if you want text mode (easy) or setup the math fonts so that they use your text font for numbers (not so easy).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for your suggestion.  `siunitx` doesn't make a difference, instead it transposes the comma from the input to a dot in the output.  I believe, I have to do it the hard way, by defining text digits to be the math digits ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You just need a math setup using the text font for digits:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{T}[3]{>{\textfont0=\the\font\DC@{#1}{#2}{#3}}c<{\DC@end}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
12,34\\
\begin{tabular}{T{,}{,}{2}}
  12,34
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}%
```

or better to get the comma  as well, `T{,}{\mbox{,}}{2}`

Comment: Hello David, thank you very much for your suggestion.  I marked it solved, as it indeed solves the problem given in my MWE.  Unfortunately it does not solve my original problem with the Stone fonts I am using. Yet, I do not understand, what the `\textfont0=\the\font\DC`magic does and how to adapt it to my fonts.

Comment: (I replaced my package for Stone with  package `bookman` due to copyright reasons.)

Comment: @Jan math uses up to 16 fonts (0 to 15) and  `\textfont0=\the\font` says that at text (as opposed to subscript) size in font 0 use the current text font at this point.  normally digits are set up to use \fam0 so this changes the digits, but if some package changes that they will not. just make a simple document that just uses the package and has $123\showlists$  and see what \fam it uses for digits, change the `0` to whatever number is needed

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.  But I cannot get `\showlists` to work.  Unknown command.  Even if I strip the document to be `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}$123\showlists$\end{document}`.  I found some other docs on the internet using `\showlists` but neither is loading an extra package.  What is going wrong? Even if I run `latex` or `pdflatex`

Comment: @Jan `\showlists` is a tex primitive it shouldn't be undefined:-) use `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\showoutput$12\showlists$
\end{document}` and you should see `.\fam0 1`

Comment: I used `article` already :-) `fam4` is the answer!  Meanwhile, the font is the correct one!  We are getting closer!  Thanks my friend!  But I do get some weird output in the pdf: `@,,212,34@end` instead of the desired 12,34.   I had to replace the `c` in your answer by `D`.   That gives the desired result, but still some errors in the log :-/

Comment: @Jan did you forget the `\makeatletter` ?