# How to use sans-serif in dcolumn (decimal alignment)?

Tags: sans-serif, dcolumn

I am setting some timetables in a sans font. I'd like to use `dcolumn` for aligning the times on the decimal point, but the package assumes you are using math.

Is there an easy way to defeat this and have `dcolumn` set the columns in the current or specified font? I will not be needing any math symbols.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376113/package-dcolumn-displays-different-fonts/376127#376127

Comment: Thanks you — nice idea; unfortunately it has no effect at all. No matter, there are other ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sansmath`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn,sansmath}

\newenvironment{sftabular}
 {\sffamily\mathversion{sans}\tabular}
 {\endtabular}

\begin{document}

\begin{sftabular}{lD{.}{.}{2.2}}
xyz &  2.1 \\
abc & 12.2 \\
uvw &  1.21
\end{sftabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]